# How to return python script response as Http response using Django framework

Tags: python, django, api, httpresponse, amazon-product-api

I am using Python Django framework, new to it.

I am getting "None" in the browser, not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
 from amazon.api import AmazonAPI
 AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = "cant share my key"
 AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = "cant share my key"
 AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG = "cant share my tag"
 REGION = "US"
 amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)

 products = amazon.search(BrowseNode='3760911', SearchIndex='Beauty', 
 MaximumPrice='30')

 for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
    return HttpResponse(print(str(product)))
```

The code works like a charm when I run in python shell however it doesn't run in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
    return HttpResponse(print(str(product)))
```

There are two problems here:

- You don't need `print`. HttpResponse accepts a string and renders it to web browsers.
- You can only `return` once.

The simplest solution I can think of is:

```
resp = ''
for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
    resp += str(product) + '<br>'
return HttpResponse(resp)
```

Comment: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: It's probably a problem when you copy-paste. Delete it, type the code yourself to see what'll happen?

Comment: Thanks. It works now however it doesnt show results on new line...How can i do that?

Comment: Change `\n` to `<br>` probably works. Can you check that?

Comment: It does work and you are simply great. Thanks a lot for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

django use MVT!
you need to create a project, set URL and put HTTPResponse in view!
read this tutorial:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html

Comment: Thats what I have done..This code is in my views.py file

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
    return HttpResponse(print(str(product)))
```

First of all, you can place HttpResponse inside the loop. The best solution is to generate your response string first and then return that string. Also, remove print.

```
for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
     response_string += product
return HttpResponse(response_string)
```